# Pascal's Triangle Algorithm JAVA JSP

Tags: java, algorithm, jsp, netbeans, pascals-triangle

I tried to make an Algorithm who show Pascal's triangle with degree 5

this is the code :

```
<%@page import="java.util.Scanner"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%!int i;       
int j;       
int n=5;       
int [] [] triangle;
        %>

        <% 
            System.out.println("Les nombres n :");
triangle=new int[n][n]; 
triangle[0][0]=1;

for(i = 1; i < n ; i++ )
{            
triangle[i][0] = 1;                        
for(j = 1; j < i ; j++ )
{               
    triangle[i][j] = triangle[i-1][j-1]+triangle[i-1][j];           
}                       
triangle[i][j] = 1;      
}              

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{        
for(j = 0; j<n ;j++)
{         
  if(triangle[i][j]!=0)        
  System.out.print(triangle[i][j] +" ");  
}      
System.out.println();  
}
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run the jsp file , nothing is happening (blank page)

Do you know what the problem please ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` prints to the console, not the network. You'll need to use `out.println()` instead, where `out` is a `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter` and is provided in the JSP.

Comment: Thanks  Mr Jeremy , that was indeed the issue. I cannot choose your post as the answer to my question unfortunatly , have to wait 9 minutes for that. Thx anyway